# error while embedding SWF into FLEX project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

trying to embed SWF into a FLEX project, importing symbols from it, not whole SWF

and compiler shows errors like this: "Unable to transcode assets swf", but SWF is correct, its version is 10.2 and actionscript version is 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error was in making symbols in flash

when you convert an object to a symbol, you should select an option "Export for Actionscript"

after that this symbols will be able to get embedded in flex app